# Is there a way to avoid borrowing `*branch` more than once in a while loop

Tags: rust, depth-first-search

I'm trying to implement the logic to take json like below as input

```json
[{"key": "a", "children": [{"key": "a1", "children": [{"key": "a11", "children": []}]}]}, {"key": "b", "children": [{"key": "b1", "children": [{"key": "b11", "children": []}]}]}]
```

and the expected output is

```json
{"a": {"a1": {"a11": ""}}, "b": {"b1": {"b11": ""}}}
```

my main function is listed as below

```rs
use serde_json::{json, Value};
use std::{collections::VecDeque};

fn convert_tree(lst: &Vec<serde_json::Value>) -> serde_json::Value {
    let mut tree = serde_json::Map::new();
    let mut queue = VecDeque::new();
    queue.push_back((lst,  &mut tree));
    while let Some((entries, branch)) = queue.pop_front() {
        for entry in entries {
            let key = entry["key"].as_str().unwrap();
            let children = entry["children"].as_array();
            if let Some(children) = children {
                let child_branch = serde_json::Map::new();
                branch.insert(key.to_owned(), serde_json::Value::Object(child_branch));
                let mut branch_ref = branch.get_mut(key).unwrap().as_object_mut().unwrap();
                queue.push_back((children, &mut branch_ref));
            } else {
                branch.insert(key.to_owned(), serde_json::Value::String("".to_owned()));
            }
        }
    }
    serde_json::Value::Object(tree)
}


#[test]
fn test_convert_tree(){
    let a_str = r#"[{"key": "a", "children": [{"key": "a1", "children": [{"key": "a11", "children": []}]}]}, {"key": "b", "children": [{"key": "b1", "children": [{"key": "b11", "children": []}]}]}]"#;
    let v: Vec<serde_json::Value>= serde_json::from_str(a_str).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", v);
    let zed = convert_tree(&v);
}
```

`cargo test --package flashlight --example test_serde_json2 -- test_convert_tree --exact --nocapture` runs into error

```bash
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*branch` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> examples/test_serde_json2.rs:68:17
   |
68 |                 branch.insert(key.to_owned(), serde_json::Value::Object(child_branch));
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
69 |                 let mut branch_ref = branch.get_mut(key).unwrap().as_object_mut().unwrap();
   |                                      ------------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
70 |                 queue.push_back((children, &mut branch_ref));
   |                 -------------------------------------------- first borrow later used here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*branch` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> examples/test_serde_json2.rs:69:38
   |
62 |     while let Some((entries, branch)) = queue.pop_front() {
   |                                         ----------------- first borrow used here, in later iteration of loop
...
69 |                 let mut branch_ref = branch.get_mut(key).unwrap().as_object_mut().unwrap();
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `*branch` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop

error[E0597]: `branch_ref` does not live long enough
  --> examples/test_serde_json2.rs:70:44
   |
62 |     while let Some((entries, branch)) = queue.pop_front() {
   |                                         ----------------- borrow later used here
...
70 |                 queue.push_back((children, &mut branch_ref));
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
71 |             } else {
   |             - `branch_ref` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*branch` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> examples/test_serde_json2.rs:72:17
   |
62 |     while let Some((entries, branch)) = queue.pop_front() {
   |                                         ----------------- first borrow later used here
...
69 |                 let mut branch_ref = branch.get_mut(key).unwrap().as_object_mut().unwrap();
   |                                      ------------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
72 |                 branch.insert(key.to_owned(), serde_json::Value::String("".to_owned()));
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0499, E0597.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
warning: `flashlight` (example "test_serde_json2" test) generated 1 warning
error: could not compile `flashlight` due to 4 previous errors; 1 warning emitted
```

The reason I use `branch` as mutable more than once at a time is because I have to fetch a mutable reference to what I just inserted in the Map, if I can do these two step once, then the problem would be gone.

I think my problem would be solved if `serde_json::Map` has a method similar to `try_insert` in `std::collections::HashMap`.

---

Even I make to combine the previously mentioned two steps together,
I just reaslize actually I was mutably borrowing `branch` in every iteration, does that also count as `"more than once at a time"`?

```rs
fn insert_and_get<'a>(map: &'a mut Map<String, Value>, key: String, value: Value) -> &'a mut Value {
    map.entry(key).or_insert(value)
}


fn convert_tree(lst: &Vec<serde_json::Value>) -> serde_json::Value {
    let mut tree = serde_json::Map::new();
    let mut queue = VecDeque::new();
    queue.push_back((lst,  &mut tree));
    while let Some((entries, branch)) = queue.pop_front() {
        for entry in entries {
            let key = entry["key"].as_str().unwrap();
            let children = entry["children"].as_array();
            if let Some(children) = children {
                let child_branch = json!({});
                let zed = insert_and_get(branch, key.to_owned(), child_branch).as_object_mut().unwrap();
                queue.push_back((children, zed));
            } else {
                branch.insert(key.to_owned(), serde_json::Value::String("".to_owned()));
            }
        }
    }
    serde_json::Value::Object(tree)
}
```

Comment: I will note that the best way to implement this is not how you're doing it now, but rather by instructing `serde` to deserialize them correctly from the beginning.

Comment: What are the possible types for keys?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I’m not sure I understand what you’re asking. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I see that `key` can be string. Can it be number? Array? Object? Null? Bool?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman you can suppose it is limited to string

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The keys of the items in the array are constant. here I only care about `key` and `children`

Comment: But what types can they have?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman originally it is from a JSON string, so value corresponds to `key` has string type, value corresponds to `children` has array type

Comment: It will be much easier if instead of using `serde_json::Value` you will use custom structs: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b0c99a88b0b7f9564aec0a33f2dbcfe5.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman you did it recursively, just like BallpointBen did

Comment: Yes, but much nicer.

Comment: Is it important that the innermost items are `""`? It is much simpler for them to be `{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an iterative solution.

```rust
use serde_json::{Map, Value};

pub fn convert_tree(list: &[Value]) -> Option<Value> {
    // Contains a tuple of:
    // - the parent list as an iterator
    // - the parent map
    // - the key that the current map/iterator belongs to in the parent map
    let mut stack: Vec<(std::slice::Iter<Value>, Map<String, Value>, String)> = vec![];
    // Iterator of all the items that go into the current map
    let mut current_iter = list.iter();
    // Map containing all the items that we have consumed from the iterator
    let mut current_map = Map::new();

    // Loop until the stack is empty.
    //
    // Normally I'd do `while let Some(item) = stack.pop()`, but since we start with an item
    // in-progress (known to be an array), the pop isn't the first thing in the loop, so `while`
    // can't be used.
    let final_map = loop {
        // There are more items in the current iterator, so we must descend into the tree.
        if let Some(next) = current_iter.next() {
            // Validation
            let obj = next.as_object()?;
            let key = obj.get("key")?.as_str()?;
            let children = obj.get("children")?.as_array()?;

            // Push the current state onto the stack
            stack.push((current_iter, current_map, key.to_owned()));

            // Descend the tree
            current_iter = children.iter();
            current_map = Map::new();

        // There are no more items in the current iterator, so we must insert this result to the
        // current map.
        } else if let Some((parent_iter, mut parent_map, key)) = stack.pop() {
            // Insert the current map the parent map
            if current_map.is_empty() {
                // Transform any `{}` values into `""`
                parent_map.insert(key, Value::String("".to_owned()));
            } else {
                // Maps with contents are inserted unchanged
                parent_map.insert(key, Value::Object(current_map));
            }

            // Ascend the tree
            current_iter = parent_iter;
            current_map = parent_map;

        // There are no more parents, so this is the fully-formed answer
        } else {
            break current_map;
        }
    };

    Some(Value::Object(final_map))
}
```

I've changed `&Vec<Value>` to `&[Value]` [for reasons explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/6274355). I've also made the return `Option<Value>` as minimal error handling.

I've tried to make this as refactorable as possible in three areas. First, the validation.

```rust
// Validation
let obj = next.as_object()?;
let key = obj.get("key")?.as_str()?;
let children = obj.get("children")?.as_array()?;
```

This would not be needed if you make the function accept a stronger type. For example, you could use this:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct KeyAndChildren {
    key: String,
    children: Vec<KeyAndChildren>,
}

pub fn convert_tree(list: &[KeyAndChildren]) -> Value { ... }
```

With this, validation is moved to the caller, and your function no longer needs an error path.

Second, the special case for the empty string.

```rust
if current_map.is_empty() {
    // Transform any `{}` values into `""`
    parent_map.insert(key, Value::String("".to_owned()));
} else {
    // Maps with contents are inserted unchanged
    parent_map.insert(key, Value::Object(current_map));
}
```

If you can accept `{}` instead of `""` for empty maps, this conditional is unnecessary and the second branch can always be used instead.

Third, whether to consume the list or not. If you don't need the list after calling `convert_tree`, you can avoid all the string allocations by consuming the list.

```rust
pub fn convert_tree(list: &[Value]) -> Option<Value>
pub fn convert_tree(list: Vec<Value>) -> Option<Value>
```

Inside the function, you will use `into_iter` instead of `iter` and match the `Value` variants to obtain their owned contents.

```rust
// Validation
let Value::Object(mut obj) = next else {
    return None;
};
let Value::String(key) = obj.get_mut("key")?.take() else {
    return None;
};
let Value::Array(children) = obj.get_mut("children")?.take() else {
    return None;
};
```

Using owned values also allows you to do validation incrementally with a struct. Here I'm using `Vec<Value>` instead of `Vec<KeyAndChildren>` from above since I need to use `children` to create an iterator over `Value`.

```rust
#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
struct KeyAndChildren {
    key: String,
    children: Vec<Value>,
}
let KeyAndChildren { key, children } = serde_json::from_value(next).ok()?;
```

[Here's both borrowed and owned versions on playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=584686416827d6432539fbb7809c61e8)

Answer (score 1):

For problems like this the easiest way is usually recursion.

```rust
fn convert_tree(lst: &[serde_json::Value]) -> serde_json::Value {
    let tree = lst
        .iter()
        .map(|item| {
            let key = item["key"].as_str().unwrap().to_owned();
            let children = if let Some(children) = item["children"].as_array() {
                convert_tree(children)
            } else {
                Value::String("".to_owned())
            };
            (key, children)
        })
        .collect();

    serde_json::Value::Object(tree)
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your solution and have upvoted it. However, I would still like to work on my current attempt for two reasons. Firstly, I want to learn by doing it iteratively. Secondly, I believe that working on my own solution will help me better understand the problem

Comment: It's going to be kind of tricky. You'll need to use `RefCell`, which is generally not all that pretty.